# Laravel 8 Query - Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

Tags: php, laravel

I am displaying a list of cars, all of which are owned by different users.  My car model has a relationship to my user model with a `user_id` foreign key.  I am trying to query the cars through the model by the users *first_name*, but I am getting a `Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string` error.  If I just query the *usercar* model, search works fine, but craps out as soon as I try to add user model columns into the query.

**Usercar.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Traits\BelongsToTenant;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Usercar extends Model
{
    use BelongsToTenant;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function car()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Car::class, 'car_id');
    }

    public static function search($query)
    {
        return empty($query) ? static::query()
            : static::where('car_id', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('car_class', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                
                // Problem starts here
                ->orWhereHas('user', function($query){
                    $query->where('first_name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
                });
    }
}
```

**ShowUserCars.php**

```
...
    public function render()
    {
        $query = Usercar::search($this->search)
            ->with('user')
            ->orderBy($this->sortField, $this->sortAsc ? 'asc' : 'desc');

        return view('livewire.show-user-cars', [
            'usercars' => $query->paginate($this->perPage),
            'currentUser' => auth()->user()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: because `$query` is the query you are building not the variable passed to the `search` method ... variable scope ... `function ($query) { ...`  in this scope `$query` is the builder ...  once you fix that naming issue you will then have another scoping issue after it

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @lagbox for the direction.  I was able to find a solution with the code below.

```
...
->orWhereHas('user', function($q) use($query){
     $q->where('first_name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
  });
...
```

Comment: mark your answer as accepted when you can so its not left as unanswered

Comment: Its says in 2 days.